# Building \ installing PHP

Tags: php, centos

I've followed this guide: http://www.phamviet.net/2012/06/03/centos-6-2-compile-php-5-4-2-from-source/

It all works as it should, but when I'm done and I type 'service httpd restart' following by 'php --version', it still displays the old 5.1.6 PHP version.

This is 'uname -a' : `Linux xxxxxx.com 2.6.32-042stab061.2 #1 SMP Fri Aug 24 09:07:21 MSK 2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux`

It's a VPS hosted in my main dedicated server (OpenVZ) and the OS is CentOS 6.

Comment: Did you remove the old php version? It's not the best idea to install a self build one together with the system provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That guide misses the (critical) complication process (the authors probably assumed you would do it yourself).

Execute:

```
make
sudo make install
```

If you have more than one cpu, running `make -j4` will speed it up (replace `4` with the number of CPUs you have). If you are running the `make` as root, remove the `sudo`.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply,
Ive tried out your answer, but it gives me this error:

libtool: link: `Zend/zend_execute.lo' is not a valid libtool object
make: *** [libphp5.la] Error 1

Thanks!

Comment: It's difficult to say from here, I don't have a similar environment to test this out. Do you absolutely need PHP 5.4.2? You can get PHP5.4 without any compilation here: http://www.webtatic.com/packages/php54/

Comment: Do you see any errors about compiling zend_execute.lo? Do you have enough RAM to compile? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/970385/php-5-2-9-build-fails-on-zend-execute-lo-out-of-memory might be relevant.

Comment: As long as it's 5.4.* I'm happy, but it gives this error: error: Failed dependencies:
        rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1 is needed by webtatic-release-6-2.noarch
        rpmlib(PayloadIsXz) <= 5.2-1 is needed by webtatic-release-6-2.noarch
And I've Google'd that before, but no progress whatsoever.

Anyhow, if you can help with that thanks.

Comment: The server have 3GB ram (burst) doubt that's an issue. If it needs more, let me know, can use up to 20GB.

Comment: Trying doing: `wget http://repo.webtatic.com/yum/el6/latest.rpm; yum install latest.rpm` to see if `yum` can resolve the dependencies for you. Since it's your host, you should poke `/proc/user_beancounters` and see if you are hitting any resource limits that need increasing.

Comment: I tried what you asked me, this is what error it gives: warning: rpmts_HdrFromFdno: Header V4 DSA signature: NOKEY, key ID cf4c4ff9 Public key for latest.rpm is not installed"

Anyhow, here's what the /proc/users_beancounters tells me: http://slypaste.org/ifC4jjIk# - Thanks!

Comment: Try adding a `--nogpgcheck` to the `yum` command.

Comment: I get the following error: ERROR with rpm_check_debug vs depsolve:
rpmlib(FileDigests) is needed by webtatic-release-6-2.noarch
rpmlib(PayloadIsXz) is needed by webtatic-release-6-2.noarch
Complete!
(1, [u'Please report this error in http://bugs.centos.org/yum5bug'])

I tried ignoring it and proceeding with the installed, it failed.